# Multi Project Maven and AWS CodeBuild

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am new to Maven, and i am working on a project that have one or more dependencies on my other projects.

Example: I have 3 maven projects.

- MyProject
- MyProjectOther
- MyProjectCommon

Both MyProject and MyProjectOther are independent of each other and do not have much to do with each other, but they both have a dependency on MyProjectCommon. (MyProjectOther dose not matter much to this question, just included it to show that MyProjectCommon is used in other projects)

Locally i can make this work, i have a workspace where i have both packages. I understand this is because Maven stores MyProjectCommon in a local repository.

Both projects (MyProject and MyProjectCommon) have their own GitHub repository, and my AWS CodeBuild is directed to build the MyProject repository. This fails as MyProjectCommon dose not exists for AWS CodeBuild.

- How can i get this build to work with AWS CodeBuild, getting CodeBuild to download and build MyProjectCommon before it builds MyProject?

MyProject `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>myproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproject.common</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

MyProjectCommon `pom.xml`

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject.common</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>myproject.common</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way of doing this on any CI system that does not understand how underlying build dependencies are resolved and/or have 'always consistent' cached artifacts.

You do have couple of options here though. First option is to publish your artifact from the library build. You'll in this case have to setup multiple projects in CodeBuild, one for MyProject and other for MyProjectCommon. Builds for MyProjectCommon would publish artifacts to S3 (codebuild can do this) and then builds for MyProject can download the published artifact from S3 (you can also replace S3 with maven repositories but you'll have to publish the artifacts).

Other more saner option is to use maven modules to solve this issue (maven reactor) and create single repository for MyProjectCommon and MyProject. Essentially your projects end up under same repository and are built in the dependency order as specified in the pom of individual projects. Here's more documentation on the maven modules https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

In the example you have, you'll still keep the pom file for MyProject and MyProjectCommon, but create another parent pom that defines both MyProject and MyProjectCommon as modules. You can then create CodeBuild project for this repository and run for example 'mvn install' which will compile both MyProjectCommon and MyProject in dependency order. You'll have an option to publish multiple artifacts from your build in CodeBuild or single zip with artifacts for both MyProject and MyProjectCommon.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @awsnitin it helped a lot, i am yet to look at the link you provided. But with going with one repository how would this work with my other Package, MyProjectOther also having a dependency on MyProjectCommon.
I am not limited to Maven, are there other build systems that can solve this problem for me?

Comment: You would need to use build tool that natively understands dependency management of the other build tools you're using. One such example is gradle, which can plug into your tools. I have not played with gradle + monorepo with multiple submodules before, but sounds doable. I would suggest reading about gradle + dependency management https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html. Fyi, certainly there are more tools and/or approaches to handle dependency management if you don't want to tie yourself to single build tool, I suggest exploring a bit more.

Comment: I looked into Gradle and that was able to solve my problem of have multiple reps and projects. Still looking for how to make it work with AWS CodeBuild though :)

Comment: @Androme did you ever get this working on AWS CodeBuild?

Comment: @Androme: did you get it work with CodeBuild? Having a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418896/how-to-do-a-gradle-composite-build-in-docker