# How to do a Gradle composite build in Docker?

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I am able to do a [Gradle composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) locally.

Now I'm trying to build the docker image in a docker container instead of on my local laptop. And I got this error:

```
Included build '/home/yang-liu/eCommerceServiceDataAccessLayer' does not exist.
```

So it complains that above package doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how to build docker image inside docker container when multiple packages are involved. My two packages are in different GitHub repositories.

## More Context

#### Project structure

[image]

#### settings.gradle files

`settings.gradle` for `eCommerceService`:

```
rootProject.name = 'eCommerceService'

includeBuild("../eCommerceServiceDataAccessLayer")
```

`settings.gradle` for `eCommerceServiceDataAccessLayer`:

```
rootProject.name = 'eCommerceServiceDataAccessLayer'
```

#### Dockerfile in eCommerceService

```
########################################################################################
# We are multi-stage builds here to build the docker image.
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
########################################################################################

########################################################################################
# Build Stage
########################################################################################
FROM openjdk:11 AS BUILD_ARTIFACT
RUN ls
ARG APP_NAME=ecommerce-service
ARG USER_NAME=yang-liu
ENV APP_HOME=/home/$USER_NAME/$APP_NAME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew $APP_HOME
COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873971/docker-cache-gradle-dependencies
RUN ./gradlew build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew build

########################################################################################
# Run Stage
########################################################################################

FROM openjdk:11-jre AS RUN_ARTIFACT
# Run as a non-root user to mitigate security risks
# https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106860/can-a-root-user-inside-a-docker-lxc-break-the-security-of-the-whole-system
ARG GROUP_NAME=ecommerce-service
ARG USER_NAME=yang-liu
ARG APP_NAME=ecommerce-service
ARG USER_NAME=yang-liu
ENV APP_HOME=/home/$USER_NAME/$APP_NAME
RUN addgroup $GROUP_NAME

ENV APP_HOME=/home/$USER_NAME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN adduser --ingroup $GROUP_NAME $USER_NAME --home $APP_HOME
USER $USER_NAME

# Copy the artifact from BUILD_ARTIFACT stage
COPY --from=BUILD_ARTIFACT  $APP_HOME/build/libs/eCommerceService-0.0.1.jar eCommerceService-0.0.1.jar

# Set ENTRYPOINT in exec form to run the container as an executable
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-classpath", "-jar","eCommerceService-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Comment: You need to add your dockerfile to this with a minimal reproducible example for anyone to be able to help unfortunately.